# Splot behavior when plotting with lines

Tags: gnuplot

I recently stumbled upon an example where Gnuplot produces (at least for me) an unexpected result so I was wondering whether it is indeed the desired behavior. The setup is following:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output plot3d?"plot1.png":"plot0.png"

unset key
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set xr [0.5:2.5]
set yr [-0.5:4.5]

set multiplot layout 1,2

$data0 << EOD
1   2   1
2   4   1
1   3   1


1   0   1
2   2   1
1   1   1
EOD

$data1 << EOD
1   2   1
2   4   1
1   3   1

1   0   1
2   2   1
1   1   1
EOD


if(plot3d){
    set view map
    splot $data0 w lp, \
        '' u 1:2:3:(sprintf("%d", $0)) w labels offset char 0, char -0.5

    splot $data1 w lp, \
        '' u 1:2:3:(sprintf("%d", $0)) w labels offset char 0, char -0.5
}else{
    plot $data0 w lp, \
        '' u 1:2:(sprintf("%d", $0)) w labels offset char 0, char -0.5

    plot $data1 w lp, \
        '' u 1:2:(sprintf("%d", $0)) w labels offset char 0, char -0.5
}
```

The two data blocks differ only in white space, `$data0` has two blank lines, while `$data1` just one. With `plot3d=1`, the script produces (5.0 patchlevel 6)
[image]

Interestingly, also points 1 and 4 in data block `$data1` are connected. This edge seems to disappear when the empty line is commented out. Digressing to plot (`plot3d=0`) yields an expected result:
[image]

I am probably missing something obvious, although the documentation seems to state that (perhaps it's somehow overridden by splot):

> Single blank records designate discontinuities in a `plot`; no line will join
>    points separated by a blank records (if they are plotted with a line style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour you describe is correct for `splot`. Indeed, the quote you show explicitely mentions `plot` and not `splot`. For `splot` behaviour see the documentation for "splot > data-file", where it says:

> Single blank records separate datablocks in a `splot` datafile; `splot` treats datablocks as the equivalent of function y-isolines. No line will join points separated by a blank record. If all datablocks contain the same number of points, gnuplot will draw cross-isolines between datablocks, connecting corresponding points. This is termed "grid data",...

So, in general, single blank lines are used to structure gridded data for `splot` or to allow selecting data points and data blocks using `every`.

Two blank lines always have the same meaning to separate two data sets, which can be selected with `index`.

Comment: thank you for the thorough explanation... :) my question was motivated by someone recently [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44055951/5351549) about strange contours in a 3d plot, he/she was plotting the contours from a file (generated previously with `table`) and the result was quite strange - the reason seemed to be exactly the fact that individual contours in the generated file were delimited only with a single blank line...